# call a function from within another function in bash

Tags: bash

I have a very simple function that prints a banner when the work of the script is complete. This is all it does:

```
 end_banner() {

    echo "*********************************************"
    echo "*         Your work in AWS is done          *"
    echo "*********************************************"

}
```

But when I call that function from the other functions in my script, it does not get invoked.

For example I try to call the end_banner function from this function:

```
    create_instance() {
  ...lines that do stuff...
  end_banner
}
```

And the output in the end_banner function does not get printed out. It doesn't even show up when I run the script with bash -x. It's like that end_banner line isn't even there.

Here's a minimal version of my entire script, with full versions of end_banner, create_volume and create_instance:

```
end_banner() {
echo "*********************************************"
echo "*         Your work in AWS is done          *"
echo "*********************************************"
}

main() {
  # 1 Lab
  if [ "$accountnumber" == 123456789 ]; then
     "$user_action"
     return
  fi

}

choose_account() {
  echo "1 Lab"
  echo "Please enter a number for the account you want to work in."
  printf "Choose AWS Account: "
  read -r aws_account_number
  echo
# 1 Lab
if [ "$aws_account_number" -eq 1 ]; then
     aws_account="Company Lab"
     aws_key="lab"
     accountnumber=123456789
     return
fi
}

choose_action() {
  echo "These are the actions possible in AWS: "
  echo
  echo "5 Create Volume"
  echo "20 Create AWS Instance"
  echo; echo
  printf "Enter an action in AWS: "
  read -r action
  echo
  # 5 Create AWS Volume
  if [ "$action" -eq "5" ]; then
    user_action=create_volume
    return
  # 20 Create AWS Instance
  elif [ "$action" -eq "20" ]; then
    user_action=create_instance
    return
  fi

}


create_volume() { 
echo "*   Create an EBS volume in AWS $aws_account  *"
echo

 printf "Enter a volume name: "
 read -r volume_name
 echo
    # Lab
    if [ "$accountnumber" -eq 123456789 ]; then
    echo "Availability Zones for $aws_account"
    echo "AZ 1: us-east-1a"
    echo "AZ 2: us-east-1b"
    echo
    fi

    #Availability Zones
    printf "Enter availability zone\\nExample. Type out: us-east-1a\\n"
    printf "AZ: "
    read -r availability_zone
    echo

    # Volume Size
    printf "Enter size: "
    read -r volume_size
    echo

    # Create from snapshot
    printf "Create from snapshot (y/n): "
    read -r from_snapshot
    echo
    if [[ "$from_snapshot" = [Yy] ]]; then 
      printf "Enter Snapshot ID: "
        read -r snapshot_id
      echo
    else 
      printf "No Snapshot Required\\n\\n"
    fi

    # Add encryption
    printf "Encrypted (y/n): "
    read -r encrypted
    echo
    if [[ "$encrypted" = [Yy] ]]; then 
      printf "Enter KMS Key ID: "
        read -r kms_key_id
      echo
    else 
      printf "No Encryption Required\\n\\n"
    fi

    # Set the Owner / Application / Engagement
    printf "Enter the Owner Name: "
    read -r owner
    echo
    printf "Enter the application name: "
    read -r application
    echo
    printf "Enter the engagement code: "
    read -r engagement
    echo

  # Create the volume based on the above
    if [[ "$from_snapshot" = [Yy] ]]; then 
        #Create EBS Volume from Snapshot"
        volume_id=$(aws ec2 create-volume --size "$volume_size" --availability-zone "$availability_zone"  --snapshot-id "$snapshot_id" --volume-type gp2  --tag-specifications "ResourceType=volume,Tags=[{Key=\"Name\",Value=\"$volume_name\"},{Key=Engagement,Value=\"$engagement\"},{Key=\"Owner\", Value=\"$owner\"},{Key=\"Application\", Value=\"$application\"}]" --profile="$aws_key" | jq -r '.VolumeId')
        return
    elif [[ "$encrypted" = [Yy] ]]; then
        #Create EBS Volume with KMS Key"
        volume_id=$(aws ec2 create-volume --size "$volume_size" --availability-zone "$availability_zone" --kms-key-id="$kms_key_id" --volume-type gp2  --tag-specifications "ResourceType=volume,Tags=[{Key=\"Name\",Value=\"$volume_name\"},{Key=\"Engagement\",Value=\"$engagement\"},{Key=\"Owner\", Value=\"$owner\"},{Key=\"Application\", Value=\"$application\"}]" --profile="$aws_key" | jq -r '.VolumeId')
    elif [[ "$from_snapshot" = [Yy] && "$encrypted" = [Yy] ]]; then
        #Create EBS Volume from snapshot with KMS Key"
        volume_id=$(aws ec2 create-volume --size "$volume_size" --availability-zone "$availability_zone"  --snapshot-id "$snapshot_id" --volume-type gp2 --profile="$aws_key" --tag-specifications "ResourceType=volume,Tags=[{\"Key=Name,Value=\"$volume_name\"},{Key=\"Engagement\",Value=\"$engagement\"},{Key=\"Owner\", Value=\"$owner\"},{Key=\"Application\", Value=\"$application\"}]" --profile="$aws_key" |  jq -r '.VolumeId')
    else
        #Create a plain volume without snapshot and encryption
        volume_id=$(aws ec2 create-volume --size "$volume_size" --availability-zone "$availability_zone" --volume-type gp2 --tag-specifications "ResourceType=volume,Tags=[{Key=\"Name\",Value=\"$volume_name\"},{Key=\"Engagement\",Value=\"$engagement\"},{Key=\"Owner\", Value=\"$owner\"},{Key=\"Application\", Value=\"$application\"}]" --profile="$aws_key" | jq -r '.VolumeId')
    fi
  sleep 10
    echo "Volume created is:  $volume_id"
  echo
  local VOLID=$1
  eval $VOLID="$volume_id"
 }



 create_instance() {


echo "  Create An Instance in AWS $aws_account"


printf "Enter Platform\\n"
printf "Example: Windows / Linux\\n"
printf "Plaform: "
read -r platform

# using LAB  amis for now
if [ \( "$platform" = "Windows" \) ] || [ \( "$platform" = "windows" \) ]; then
  ami="ami-03bfe6d8e0e60051c"
elif [ \( "$platform" = "Linux" \) ]  || [ \( "$platform"  = "linux" \) ]; then
  ami="ami-4fb38358"
else
  printf "That is not a valid choice."
fi

printf "Enter an Instance Type: "
read -r instance_type

printf "Enter Number of Instances: "
read -r num_instances

printf "Enter a Subnet ID: "
read -r subnet_id

printf "Enter Security Group ID: "
read -r security_group

printf "Enter a key name: "
read -r key_name

printf "Enter a server name: "
read -r name_tag

printf "Enter an application name: "
read -r application_tag

printf "Enter an engagement code: "
read -r engagement_tag

printf "Enter an owner name: "
read -r owner_tag

printf "Enter a role: "
read -r role_tag

## Launch the instance
tag_instance_id=$(aws ec2 run-instances --count "$num_instances" --image-id "$ami" --instance-type "$instance_type" --key-name "$key_name" --subnet-id "$subnet_id" --security-group-ids "$security_group"  --profile="$aws_key" | jq -r '.Instances[].InstanceId')
# Get volume ID and device name
root_vol=$(aws ec2 describe-instances --instance-ids "$tag_instance_id" --profile="$aws_key" | jq -r '.Reservations[].Instances[].BlockDeviceMappings[].Ebs.VolumeId')
root_vol_device_name=$(aws ec2 describe-volumes --volume-ids "$root_vol" --profile="$aws_key" | jq -r '.Volumes[].Attachments[].Device')
az=$(aws ec2 describe-instances --instance-ids "$tag_instance_id" --profile="$aws_key" | jq -r '.Reservations[].Instances[].Placement.AvailabilityZone')

echo
printf "Instance ID: %s has been created in Availability Zone: %s\\n" "$tag_instance_id" "$az"
printf "Wait till the instance is created to tag it.\\n"

sleep 15

# Tagging the new instance
aws ec2 create-tags --resources "$tag_instance_id" --tags Key=Name,Value="$name_tag"  Key=Application,Value="$application_tag" Key=Engagement,Value="$engagement_tag" Key=Owner,Value="$owner_tag" Key=Role,Value="$role_tag" --profile="$aws_key"

## Tagging the Root Volume - fixed tags
aws ec2 create-tags --resources "$root_vol" --tags Key=Name,Value="$name_tag root volume"  Key=DeviceName,Value="$root_vol_device_name" Key=Application,Value="$application_tag" Key=Engagement,Value="$engagement_tag" Key=Owner,Value="$owner_tag" Key=Role,Value="$role_tag" --profile="$aws_key"

printf  "The instance %s now has the following tags:\\n" "$tag_instance_id"
printf "Host Name: %s\\n" "$name_tag"
printf "Application: %s\\n" "$application_tag"
printf "Engagement: %s\\n" "$engagement_tag"
printf "Owner: %s\\n" "$owner_tag"
printf "Role: %s\\n" "$role_tag"

echo
printf "Do you need additional volumes (y/n): "
read -r vol_answer
if [[ "$vol_answer" = [Yy] ]]; then
  printf "Number of volumes to add: "
  read -r num_volumes
  volumes=()
  devices=( {f..z} )
  for (( i=0; i < num_volumes; i++ )); do
    CURID=''
    create_volume 'CURID'
    volumes[$i]=${CURID}
      printf "Attach volume ID: %s\\n" "${volumes[i]}"
      if [ \( "$platform" = "Windows" \) ] || [ \( "$platform" = "windows" \) ]; then
        device="/dev/sd${devices[i]}"
        aws ec2 attach-volume --volume-id "${volumes[i]}" --instance-id "$tag_instance_id" --device "$device" --profile="$aws_key" | jq '.'
        aws ec2 create-tags --resources "${volumes[i]}" --tags Key=Name,Value="$name_tag volume"  Key=DeviceName,Value="$device" Key=Application,Value="$application_tag" Key=Engagement,Value="$engagement_tag" Key=Owner,Value="$owner_tag" Key=Role,Value="$role_tag" --profile="$aws_key"
      elif [ \( "$platform" = "Linux" \) ]  || [ \( "$platform"  = "linux" \) ]; then
        device="/dev/xvd${devices[i]}"
        aws ec2 attach-volume --volume-id "${volumes[i]}" --instance-id "$tag_instance_id" --device "$device" --profile="$aws_key" | jq '.'
        aws ec2 create-tags --resources "${volumes[i]}" --tags Key=Name,Value="$name_tag volume"  Key=DeviceName,Value="$device" Key=Application,Value="$application_tag" Key=Engagement,Value="$engagement_tag" Key=Owner,Value="$owner_tag" Key=Role,Value="$role_tag" --profile="$aws_key"
      else
        printf "That is not a valid choice.\\n"
      fi  
  done
  return
elif [[ "$vol_answer" = [Nn] ]]; then
  printf "Ok. No added volumes will be created.\\n"
else
  printf "Input is incorrect.\\n"
fi
end_banner
}

choose_action
choose_account
main "$@"
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Do you call `create_instance` anywhere? If so, do you get any error when calling `end_banner` (such as `end_banner: command not found`)?

Comment: `test() { echo 'hi'; }; a() { echo 'something'; test; }; a` correctly outputs `something` and `hi`. Have you tried creating a [minimum, verifiable, complete example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) of your problem?

Comment: What operating system are you using? I found OSx Bash need `function` prefix, where Linux (Ubuntu) Bash doesn't.

Comment: I am using Ubuntu 18.04

Comment: @PraveenP No it doesn't. The function prefix is a bash extension, but it understands POSIX syntax as well.

Comment: Post the full definition of `create_instance()`

Comment: I've updated the OP with what I believe is a minimal but functional example of my entire script. I included full versions of only the create_volume function and the create_instance function. Please let me know if I posted too much information. Thanks.

Comment: Update. I've found out that end_banner is called and works correctly if I DON'T create an additional volume. If I DO create an additional volume, the contents of end_banner do not show. It's like the script is exiting when create_volume is called which does not invoke the end_banner function. 

Is there a way I can get create_volume to return to the calling function (create_instance) ONLY if it is called from within that function?

Comment: I don't want to put the end_banner function in create_volume because it could be called multiple times. And won't make sense to see the end_banner message multiple times.

Answer (score 0):

I've found the culprit.

In this part of create_instances, I had a return that was causing the program to exit before the end_banner function was called:

```
for (( i=0; i < num_volumes; i++ )); do
    CURID=''
    create_volume 'CURID'
    volumes[$i]=${CURID}
      printf "Attach volume ID: %s\\n" "${volumes[i]}"
      if [ \( "$platform" = "Windows" \) ] || [ \( "$platform" = "windows" \) ]; then
        device="/dev/sd${devices[i]}"
        aws ec2 attach-volume --volume-id "${volumes[i]}" --instance-id "$tag_instance_id" --device "$device" --profile="$aws_key" 2>&1 | sed -e 's/An error occurred (InvalidVolume.ZoneMismatch) //g' | jq '.'
        aws ec2 create-tags --resources "${volumes[i]}" --tags Key=Name,Value="$name_tag volume"  Key=DeviceName,Value="$device" Key=Application,Value="$application_tag" Key=Engagement,Value="$engagement_tag" Key=Owner,Value="$owner_tag" Key=Role,Value="$role_tag" --profile="$aws_key"
      elif [ \( "$platform" = "Linux" \) ]  || [ \( "$platform"  = "linux" \) ]; then
        device="/dev/xvd${devices[i]}"
        aws ec2 attach-volume --volume-id "${volumes[i]}" --instance-id "$tag_instance_id" --device "$device" --profile="$aws_key" 2>&1 | sed -e 's/An error occurred (InvalidVolume.ZoneMismatch) //g' | jq '.'
        aws ec2 create-tags --resources "${volumes[i]}" --tags Key=Name,Value="$name_tag volume"  Key=DeviceName,Value="$device" Key=Application,Value="$application_tag" Key=Engagement,Value="$engagement_tag" Key=Owner,Value="$owner_tag" Key=Role,Value="$role_tag" --profile="$aws_key"
      else
        printf "That is not a valid choice.\\n"
      fi
  return 
  done
```

I removed that return line and the script now works as planned. Thank you all for your input.